# Prevent application from receiving keyboard event when changing layouts

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have XKB configured with:

`setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout is,ru-is -option caps:escape grp:rctrl_switch grp:shift_caps_toggle compose:sclk shift:both_capslock`

It turns `caps` into `esc` and let's me switch layouts with `shift+caps` but applications still receive the `shift+esc` key event when changing layouts. It was tolerable until a Firefox update bound `shift+esc` to `about:processes` with no option to customise it

In essence, is there any way to prevent applications from seeing `shift+esc` when `shift+caps` is pressed while still having them see `caps` as `esc`?

I'm on arch with a bare window manager. Any help appreciated